# s3 cross account and cross region data sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket in Account A and a folder inside that bucket has read-only access to Account B.
 * Note: Buckets are in different accounts and in different regions.

How do I sync files from a bucket in account A to the bucket in Account B?

Comment: Did you read the documentation before asking the questions? What did you try and what is the error you got?

Comment: yes i did and i was able to sync them but couldn't automate the process

Comment: what is the error you are getting when trying to automate?

Comment: How are you doing the sync? Are you using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 sync` command? What do you mean by "a folder inside that bucket has read-only access to Account B"? A folder cannot have access to another account. Feel free to Edit your question to provide additional information.

Comment: bucket name xxxxx and inside the bucket, there are many folders but we have read access to only 1 folder

Comment: i used replicate feature in s3 to sync all the files but i cant download them. Error message says access denied. Source account gave us getobject and listobject permissions still not able to download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to source s3 bucket into management section(replication)
2. get started with replication and choose from all contents in bucket or use 
   prefix for a folder followed by / at end.
3. choose destination bucket and add destinations account id.
   (destination bucket should be in different region than source)
4. select change bucket ownership to the destination account and hit
   next.
5. copy the bucket policy and paste it in destinations bucket
   policy and select create new iam role.
6. review and finish the replication process.
7. once the bucket policy is pasted in destination account grab the account 
   number of source and go to replication section in destination bucket and 
   selection receive files.
8. paste the source account id and save it. now you can replicate files
   in s3 buckets.